# Finding a key in an object that’s true AND matches en entry in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array like this:

```
baseBreakpoints: [
    'xLarge',
    'large',
    'largeMedium',
    'medium',
    'smallMedium',
    'small',
    'xSmall'
]
```

… and I have an object like this:

```
breakpoints = {
    "gtMedium": true,
    "xLarge": true,
    "gtLargeMedium": true,
    "giant": false,
    "small": false,
    "ltLargeMedium": false,
    "gtLarge": true,
    "xSmall": false,
    "largeMedium": false,
    "medium": false,
    "gtSmall": true,
    "large": false,
    "smallMedium": false
}
```

I need to find the key in the object that’s `true` *and* exists in the array. For example, in this example above the value would be `xLarge` since `xLarge === true` in the object and exists in the `breakpoints` array.

Any suggestions? Lodash is already a dependency in the project, if that helps.

Comment: @FelixSFD — Why did you edit a possible solution out of my post?

Comment: Because answers have to be written as an answer and not added to the question itself

Comment: I added mine as an insecure solution. Something to get feedback on. Not as an answer.

Comment: A "question" is per definition not an "answer"

Comment: Placed it back with a bit of clarification. Please leave it unless others agree  with your reasoning.

Comment: @FelixSFD is right, answers don't belong in questions. The key point is that people should be able to vote on both the answer and the question separately, as that's what a lot of visibility of content is based on on SO. Note that you can also post an answer to your own question. If you have a new question about the code you think might be an answer, post that as a new question.

Comment: As I mentioned, I didn’t post an answer. I posted a thought that I wasn’t sure was the right direction and mentioned that I preferred a native JS answer. i.e. Not mine. But since multiple people believe it’s an incorrect use of the site I’ll wane and leave it as-is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could filter `baseBreakpoints` by looking up `breakpoints`.

```js
var baseBreakpoints = ['xLarge', 'large', 'largeMedium', 'medium', 'smallMedium', 'small', 'xSmall'],
    breakpoints = { gtMedium: true, xLarge: true, gtLargeMedium: true, giant: false, small: false, ltLargeMedium: false, gtLarge: true, xSmall: false, largeMedium: false, medium: false, gtSmall: true, large: false, smallMedium: false },
    result = baseBreakpoints.filter(k => breakpoints[k]);
    
console.log(result);
```

ES5

```js
var baseBreakpoints = ['xLarge', 'large', 'largeMedium', 'medium', 'smallMedium', 'small', 'xSmall'],
    breakpoints = { gtMedium: true, xLarge: true, gtLargeMedium: true, giant: false, small: false, ltLargeMedium: false, gtLarge: true, xSmall: false, largeMedium: false, medium: false, gtSmall: true, large: false, smallMedium: false },
    result = baseBreakpoints.filter(function (k) { return breakpoints[k]; });
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Very elegant where supported

Comment: Filter is 5.1 no?

Answer (score 1):

you can try this approach.

the first condition check if the key is truthy, the second one test if in the array there's a match.

This solution compared to the other correct answers returns a pure string rather then a filtered array.

```js
let baseBreakpoints = ['xLarge', 'large', 'largeMedium', 'medium', 
'smallMedium', 'small', 'xSmall'];

let breakpoints = {
    "gtMedium": true,
    "xLarge": true,
    "gtLargeMedium": true,
    "giant": false,
    "small": false,
    "ltLargeMedium": false,
    "gtLarge": true,
    "xSmall": false,
    "largeMedium": false,
    "medium": false,
    "gtSmall": true,
    "large": false,
    "smallMedium": false
}

let key = Object.keys(breakpoints).find(key => {
   return breakpoints[key] 
     && baseBreakpoints.some(breakpoint => breakpoint === key);
})

console.log(key);
```

Comment: Why not post the solution here where it will not disappear?

Comment: You could also use the `includes` method instead of `some`, which do you think would be faster ?

Comment: @mplungjan i've added the solution inside of my answer :)

Comment: @Taurus from the implementation of both (on MDN)  they actually execute the same logic, both loop over the array and break the loop when a match is found. in this case i don't see any difference, in a difference scenario .some is more flexible since you pass a function (that encapsulates an arbitrary condition) rather then a value.

Answer (score 0):

Fairly simple lookup

```js
var baseBreakpoints = [
    'xLarge',
    'large',
    'largeMedium',
    'medium',
    'smallMedium',
    'small',
    'xSmall'
];

var breakpoints = {
    "gtMedium": true,
    "xLarge": true,
    "gtLargeMedium": true,
    "giant": false,
    "small": false,
    "ltLargeMedium": false,
    "gtLarge": true,
    "xSmall": false,
    "largeMedium": false,
    "medium": false,
    "gtSmall": true,
    "large": false,
    "smallMedium": false
}
var res = [];
for (bp of baseBreakpoints) {
  if (breakpoints[bp] != undefined && breakpoints[bp]) res.push(bp)
}
console.log(res)
```